# Правильно ли выражение "заниматься трудом"?

Tags: семантика, тавтология

Возможно у фразы есть признаки тавтологии?

Answer (score 1):

В [**Словаре сочетаемости слов русского языка**](http://vassilenkoanatole.narod.ru/slovar-sochet_slov.pdf) находим: "Заниматься... каким-л. трудом".

В Нацкорпусе:

Необходимость предвидеть возникла у людей с того времени, как они стали **заниматься трудом**. [В. В. Мезенцев, К. С. Абильханов. Чудеса: Популярная энциклопедия. Том 2. Книга 4 (1991)]

Он отродясь **не занимался никаким общественно полезным трудом**, жил как бы в своё удовольствие, как бы в забавах всё время. [Виктор Астафьев. Пролетный гусь (2000)]

**Дополнение**

Вопрос был изменен. Теперь он и о правильности, и о тавтологичности.
Уточню мой ответ. Правильно? — да. Тавтологично? Если в обороте только два слова (*заниматься трудом*), то это, на мой взгляд, плеоназм, а точнее, многословие (в состав предложений или фраз включаются слова, не увеличивающие общую смысловую нагрузку, например: «Он шёл по направлению к дому»). Если оборот расширен (например, *заниматься общественно полезным трудом*), то он корректен со всех точек зрения.

Comment: «...Того времени, как они стали заниматься трудом». Интересно, когда настал тот исторический час, и чем был наполнен предыдущий? Как сформировались мышцы? Мгновенно? Ну да, книга-то о чудесах.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы такое (грамматически возможное) словосочетание имело смысл и было стилистически оправдано, нужен подходящий контекст, например, противопоставление труда тому, чем ещё можно "заниматься" из того, что "трудом" не принято называть:

> На исправленья путь он вскоре встал
>
> И **занялся трудом**, а не *разбоем* -
>
> Теперь он в печке выплавлял металл
>
> И ощущал себя почти героем.

Для *правильности* не так важно, какими терминами можно формально заклеймить словосочетание - никто ведь не забракует выражения "дело делать" или "шутки шутить" за тавтологичность и пр. Важнее функциональность и информативность: совершенно бессмысленно на вопрос "чем занимается работник?" отвечать просто "трудом", но может иметь смысл ответ "занимается самым неблагодарным трудом на предприятии - делает то-то".